# Sencha Touch ListView IndexBar + selectfield

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am new to *sencha* and would like to have the *indexBar* option to a *listview* which is launched by the selectfield. Tried with

```
defaultTabletPickerConfig: 
{
  listeners: 
  {
    painted: function(panel) 
    {
      var list = panel.down('list');
      list.setIndexBar(true);
    }
  }
}
```

But this code doesn't work, please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you new to sencha please do not use defaultTabletPickerConfig setting.
Please describe more what you want to get, share more code you have written.

Comment: I have a store with more than 500 records. To select the last record in the list(launched by selectfield) i have to scroll down until i come to the end. I need a indexbar where i can select and the scroll automatically happens or a AutoComplete TextField where i can type the first few letters and the list appears with the sorted records.

Comment: and what is your view? why not use simple http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-indexBar ?